# Sharing internet between Host and guest xen

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox-networking, xen

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 as host machine,want to create bridge so that guest OS can access the WiFi Internet access. If a have understood correctly brctl utility is used to create bridge for Ethernet devices. Is it possible to use same tool to create a bridge for wireless network so that my guest OS can access it.? There is no Ethernet port in my machine.

If it is possible to create bridge please provide the steps

Comment: You can't bridge to a wireless client. You have to use a routed or NAT type of network.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Hampton. I am very new to Networking, please provide few references which explains how to configure routed or NAT network and also how to verify/test whether configuration are proper.